# No value for key [org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl] bound to thread [main]

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Recently, I've updated my hibernate to version `5.2.1.Final` (the latest by now) and spring framework to `4.3.0.RELEASE`. When I start the application in class `StartUp`

```
@Service
public class StartUp {

@Autowired(required = true)
private IUserService            userSrv;

public void init() throws UnsupportedEncodingException {

  User user = userSrv.single(admin_filter);
  ....
}
}
```

and by the execution of line

```
User user = userSrv.single(admin_filter);
```

I get this exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'startUp' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No value for key [org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl@6568f998] bound to thread [main]
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:775)
  at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:861)
  at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541)
  at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:444)
  at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:326)
  at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:3827)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4334)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:791)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:771)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:525)
  at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:920)
  at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectories(HostConfig.java:883)
  at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:492)
  at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1138)
  at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:311)
  at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1053)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:719)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:443)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:516)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710)
  at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:566)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
  at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:288)
  at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:413)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No value for key [org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl@6568f998] bound to thread [main]
  at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationManager.unbindResource(TransactionSynchronizationManager.java:210)
  at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager.doCleanupAfterCompletion(HibernateTransactionManager.java:637)
  at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.cleanupAfterCompletion(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:1016)
  at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processRollback(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:883)
  at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.rollback(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:830)
  at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.completeTransactionAfterThrowing(TransactionAspectSupport.java:503)
  at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:285)
  at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
  at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
  at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
  at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy39.single(Unknown Source)
  at net.woodenstar.general.StartUp.init(StartUp.java:42)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeCustomInitMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1706)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1645)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
  ... 36 more
```

Answer (score 8):

Just Found the solution. after updating the hibernate, instead of using :

```
<bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
  <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
  <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>
```

And

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
...
</bean>
```

try these:

```
<bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager">
  <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

And

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
...
</bean>
```